# Pulling Outlook calendar invitations by POP into Gmail

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, calendar

I've got an Outlook account that I'm pulling into my Gmail using POP3. Everything works fine, except that calendar invitations from other people appear in my Gmail as plain text mails, rather than calendar invitations.
What's the secret switch to get these appearing the way I would want?

**EDIT:** To be clear, I want the calendar invitations I get via Outlook to give me the regular response buttons I get for other invitations in my Gmail, so that I can add them to my diary at the click of a button.

Comment: What's the mail client that you are using?
Does the "pulling into" mean that you imported the data from Outlook account to Gmail account or you configure an Outlook account in Gmail client?

Comment: @Jade I am using Gmail webmail, and I'm pulling Outlook mail into the Gmail using POP3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that actually calendar invitations **are** coming through properly from Outlook to Gmail...but there was one particular sender who was using Zoom to send invitations, and those were the ones coming out in a garbled format in Gmail. I'm trying to debug by working with the sender, but that is taking time. Meanwhile, since I have to award the bounty, I'll give it to @harrymc for identifying that it's a format issue.

**UPDATE:** so, I have a solution. Instead of forwarding the invitations to my Gmail, I just added my Outlook calendar to my Gmail calendar. So now I can see all my appointments in one calendar, which is all I wanted in the first place.

Admittedly this is more of a workaround than a solution, but it did what I needed, so I'm marking this as the solution.

Comment: Okay, if you have any update in the future, please don't forget to post back.

Answer (score 2):

The Google article
[What's not supported in Outlook Calendar](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/156466?hl=en)
lists the following case, among others:

| Unsupported feature | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| Rich content in calendar events | You can add rich content such as links, formatted text, and tables to a calendar description in Outlook. If you're using Outlook 2016, save the calendar events using Rich Text Format (RTF). **If you save the events as HTML, the formatting won't synchronize with other users' calendars and they only receive plain text.** |

Therefore, if the events are defined using HTML, they will be received without
any formatting, as plain text.

Your events need to be created in Rich Text Format (RTF) for the formatting to
be preserved.

Comment: Vote for you :)

Comment: Thanks for this info. Not sure if it will solve my problem. I just updated the question for clarity: I want the calendar invitations I get via Outlook to give me the regular response buttons I get for other invitations in my Gmail, so that I can add them to my diary at the click of a button. I can't control the format other people use to send me invitations. They appear as normal invitations in Outlook, but plain text in Gmail, without any "accept/tentative/decline" options. How do I get these invitations to behave as expected in Gmail?

Comment: These invitations must be in HTML, which (surprisingly) Gmail doesn't handle well. You may have to pass them via another server than Gmail to convert them to RTF, but I don't know of such.

Answer (score 2):

In  my opinion, it's suggested to create a rule to forward the meeting invitation automatically to your gmail account, so that you could choose to accept or decline in your gmail. If you have a Outlook client, you could try to create a rule via Manage rules and Alerts like below:

[image]

Comment: That sounds like a good idea! I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Does it has any update :)?